# Words to say after someone welcomes me?

Tags: word-usage

Please can someone tell me some proper words to say after someone say "Welcome to our office"? Other than just "thank you"?

Answer (score 2):

A common response would be

> It's a pleasure to be here.

You'll find countless examples, such as [Alvaro Negredo's first interview](http://www.goal.com/en-ie/news/3922/spain/2014/09/03/5080099/i-heard-nothing-from-madrid-negredo) after joining Valencia football club:

> You feel special when they welcome you this way, with this affection. **It's a pleasure to be here** and we will take Valencia to where the club deserves to be.